# Why is High Fructose Corn Syrup not available as an ingredient?

Tags: molecular-gastronomy

In the age of molecular gastronomy I am surprised that it seems to be impossible to purchase HFCS (High Fructose Corn Syrup) as an ingredient.  Why is this?

Comment: Have you been reading the [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/sophie-brickman/why-is-it-easier-to-buy-a_b_144777.html)? Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: This is an excellent question. I searched, but could not find it for sale anywhere except in industrial quantities. Now, I'd like to know the answer too!

Comment: It's quite possible this is an economics question -- if there's little demand for it in small quantities, there's little profit to be made in either bottling it or in stocking it in stores.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an economics question, not a cooking one.

Comment: @rumtscho Do you have information to demonstrate that this is an issue of economics and not food safety- for instance?

Comment: @ebpa I don't have to demonstrate that it is not food safety. "Why cannot I buy X" is a matter of either free market phenomena or market regulations. Both are about economics, even if the regulations were made on the basis of food safety concerns. The question simply has nothing to do with cooking, it is about market availability.